# ondblclick makes 2 triggers on edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML select has ondblclick method when clicked on entry - save it. But for some reason in Edge browser is triggered twice while it works perfecly fine in chrome.

```
<select id="selectId" class="form-control" th:field="*{type}" 
    size="20" multiple="multiple" style="overflow:scroll;" ondblclick=rightDblClick(this.value)>
        <option th:each="item : ${obj.types}" 
                th:value="${item.id}" 
                th:text="${item.value}"></option>
</select>

function leftDblClick(val) {
   var list = new Array();
   list.push(val);
   sendRequest(list, false) //ajax request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Edge supports these tags correctly.

If you want you can try something like:

```
document.getElementById('selectId').ondblclick = function (val) {
   var list = Array();
   list.push(val);
   sendRequest(list, false) //ajax request
}
```

I think this should work fine on Edge.

Comment: tried using also this snippet, but result is same, I think edge has problems with ondblclick functionality in general